# How to configure Spring Boot app to accept unknown SSL client certificate?

Tags: spring-boot, security, authentication, ssl, spring-security

I created a Spring Boot 2 app with 2-way SSL auth.
In short, it boils down to the following config:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().x509();
    }
```

The app has keystore/truststore and it works fine with an imported client cert.
Unexpectedly, If I try to connect with an unknown client cert, the connection is not established due to the SSL handshake failure.

However, I would like to reach the application layer even if the cert is not accepted and respond with an HTTP response from the application.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If don’t need certificate handshake at server side, that means, you don’t need `SSL`. Thus, deactivate it in your configuration file:

```
server:
  ssl:
     enabled: false
```

**PS:** Exposing your `REST` webservice in `HTTP` protocol only is hazardous. Maybe, that makes sense to have such configuration in your development environment.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: I could have used Spring Boot property

```
server.ssl.client-auth: want
```

instead of

```
server.ssl.client-auth: need
```

The first option still allows to connect to tomcat even if the cert is not valid or not present. Then the request will be rejected by security filters.